# How to use @retry with keyword arguments AND pass a function

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I am using the retrying (`pip install retrying`) package.

I have a function like this -

```
from retrying import retry
from random import randint

def a():
    number = randint(0, 10)

    if number > 0:
        print number
        raise Exception("Some exception")
    else:
        return number

# Case 1
a = retry(a)  # This works as expected - i.e. execs until I get a 0
print a()

# Case 2
a = retry(a, stop_max_attempt_number=3)
print a()
```

In Case 2, the stop_max_attempt_number is not having an effect. Is there a different way to pass a function, **AND** a keyword arg?

My use case is such that I *WANT* to decorate a function only when needed, so the typical usage of putting `@retry(stop_max_attempt_number=3)` right before `def a()` is not what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`retry` is a decorator that can either be used without arguments or with. If you give it arguments it'll act as a decorator *factory* and return the actual decorator. Call that returned decorator:

```
a = retry(stop_max_attempt_number=3)(a)
```

as that is the equivalent of using `retry()` as a decorator:

```
@retry(stop_max_attempt_number=3)
def a():
    # ...
```